# Serilog not writing to the file with Configuration loaded from appsettings.json in Console CORE 3 App

Tags: file, .net-core, serilog, ilogger

```
ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Worker Service Application.

Packages

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3"

PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.3"

PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.1.3"

PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0"

PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.0"
```

Serilog writing to the file with hard-coded LoggerConfiguration but not working from Config loaded from appsettings.json

Here is application code

```
public static class Program
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    private static string _environmentName;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        //Log.Logger = (Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:Default"] == "Debug")? 
        //    new LoggerConfiguration()
        //    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        //    .WriteTo.Console()
        //    .WriteTo.File(path: Path.Combine("C:/LogFiles", "OA-EmailService-.log"),
        //        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, shared: true, flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        //    .CreateLogger()
        //    :
        //    new LoggerConfiguration()
        //        .WriteTo.Console()
        //        .WriteTo.File(path: Path.Combine("C:/LogFiles", "OA-EmailService-.log"),
        //            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, shared: true, flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        //        .CreateLogger()
        //    ;
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("APP:App started");
            hostBuilder.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "APP:App startup failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.ClearProviders();  //Disabling default integrated logger
                _environmentName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                    //    optional: false, 
                    //    reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
            })
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); });
}
```

Here is appsettings.json

```
    {
      "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
              "outputTemplate": "===> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
              "pathFormat": "C:/LogFiles/OA-EmailService-.log",
              "outputTemplate": "===> {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Interestingly that the part for Console sink is working well, it is just problem with file. How can I force serilog to write into the file?

Comment: I don't see where you ever initialized `Configuration`.

Answer (score 5):

**1) Do you have the proper sink package installed?** You're showing the arguments for the (deprecated) rolling file sink at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile / https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/, which would have to actively be installed in order for the appsettings value to be run.

The syntax for the preferred `Serilog.Sinks.File` package would be as:

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": ".\\yourpath\\yourfile.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**2) Does the folder you've specified exist and does the executable have permission to write to the folder?** It may be silently failing if the attempt to write to the folder path isn't allowed by the file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot it resolved, strange enough I took this config from some up to date project where it works well but it was ASP.NET app not console. Thanks again

Comment: @SergeySeriakov, post your fix so others can benefit from it.